# Enable enhancements (e.g. Equalizer) with Microsoft High Definition Audio Device

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, motherboard

I have the ASrock X470 Master motherboard with integrated sound. It uses the Realtek HD audio controller, but I just use the Microsoft one because for some reason Realtek does not let me split the front and rear panel audio (I have tried everything). The only problem with using the default Microsoft controller is that I cannot use any enhancements. From my basic knowledge a simple equalizer should be able to be pulled of no matter the sound card or device, is there any way to enable it without using Realtek?

Windows 10 Home - ASrock X470 Master SLI/ac Motherboard

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, for some reason if I go to Settings App > System > Sound > Device Properties the tab shows up, but only when I go from there, kind weird!